# QED impact on Unified Field Theory

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, history, unified-theories

how did the development of quantum electrodynamics impact the development of modern unified field theories?
and did any other theories have more significant impact?

Comment: This question is opinion based, and so it will probably be rapidly closed. Perhaps, you might try asking something very specific that can be answered definitively, e.g. a very specific question on the historical development of certain aspects of physics.

Answer (score 1):

The impact of the development of quantum electrodynamics on modern field unified field theories is total, in that quantum electrodynamics is the foundation of quantum field theories as we know them. Quantum electrodynamics, initially developed by the researches of Dirac, is the first important example of a quantized field theory, i.e. the electromagnetic field was the first fundamental interaction to be successfully quantized.